# Vis.js Hierarchical visualization network algorithm changed?

Tags: reactjs, vis.js, vis.js-network

Until Vis.js-Network version 6.0.0, hierarchical like a tree with a desired form to me, but when updated to Version 6.1.1, the visualization change, there is a workaround?

I want to work with newest version

I've tried various parameters changes, like change `hierarchical.sortMethod` between directed and hubsize, but without success.

I made these two examples bellow to explain the issue

The desired form:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nvk3zw?file=Arvore.jsx

The same visualization with new version:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fmffgx?file=Arvore.jsx

---

I expect some solution to use Vis.js-Network version 6.1.1, to obtain the same result as this visualization:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nvk3zw?file=Arvore.jsx

Answer (score 0):

According Vis-Network issue [#176](https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/issues/176) will be fixed on a new version.